# Same Bat-Time! Same Bat-Channel!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story, knowledge, anagram

Robin has been captured by the always-insidious Riddler!  Batman tracks him to a old apartment on the 39th floor of an abandoned high-rise and swings inside, only for the window to slam shut behind him.  He finds the tied up Robin, frees him, and takes stock of the situation.

The walls, ceiling, floor, doors, and windows have all been reinforced.  Using the bat-devices on his suit, Batman detects a massive bomb in the floor underneath them, large enough to blow a massive hole in the building, and them besides.  The bomb's trigger is connected to...

A PC in one corner of the room.  Robin (Grayson, if you must know,) turns it on and is confronted with an image straight out of an old Sierra game:

> A pixelated Batman and Robin stand in a room almost identical to the room the real Dynamic Duo stand in.  At the top of the screen are three Batman heads in a line and one order: $Find$  $the$  $Bomb!$

As Batman looks around the rest of the room, Robin experiments with the game, which has a straightforward text parser for interaction.  Finally he puts in enters a command: *Look under floor.*

The game's Batman and Robin tear up the game's apartment floor and find nothing but darkness, both figures shrugging at the screen before being blown to smithereens in a 16-bit explosion.  Rather than some pithy Roberta Williams-penned Game Over notice, however, the message that pops up on the screen only reads: **Two Lives Left**, and the screen promptly returns to its default state, sans one Batman head at the top of the screen.  With dawning terror, Robin realizes that they only have three tries to find the bomb in the game--and he just used one!

Objects in the room include:

- On the west wall is the PC itself, an older model with a classic cathode-ray monitor.  A sticker plastered on on the side of the monitor reads,

  > "jura qv qlb hyrn eagbe rnq e bgguv egrra?"
- In the middle of the room sits a table with a long white tablecloth and a couple of cheap chairs set at it.  There is a deck of cards in the center of the table, unpacked and complete, but with one joker removed.
- An upright piano is on the east wall, next to the door.  Scratched into the upper panel is this message:

  > ### QUAVER!
  >
  > 6 **duh**, odd Chris's books  Could show enmity!
  >   8 **duh**, odd Chris's books  Could show enmity!
- Positioned against the north wall is a television, also over a decade old, with a DVD player hooked up to it.  A small collection of dvds are on the shelf underneath the DVD player:

  > - Enigma [*of course!*]
  > - Se7en
  > - The Uninvited [1944]
  > - Shutter Island
  > - Exam
  > - No Country for Old Men
  > - The Sixth Sense
  > - Prisoners
- Above the television is a well-drawn poster of the Riddler himself about to deliver a curbstomp to a bruised Batman.  Red block letters above the Riddler read "**...AIN'T THAT A KICK IN THE HEAD?**"  Scrawled on the bottom edge of the poster is the word, "**...about...**"
- Finally, in the back-left corner is a refrigerator, stocked with bread, a 24-pack of bottled water, fruit cocktail, canned meat, what have you.  Batman and Robin could survive on this for over a week.

The computer is also hooked up to the door--in typical Riddler fashion, only finishing the computer game will allow Batman and Robin's escape.  So...

> ***Where's the bomb?***
>
> !  **Hint the first:**  There are two messages you'll have to put together to determine where the bomb is, one around the TV and one at the piano.

Comment: Who invented this puzzle? This is ridiculously brilliant. However, I assume you are wanting us to find the bomb *in the game*, because batman has already found the real one. They just have to find the game bomb to escape the building.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that if you want to rearrange the letters of the message **jura qv qlb hyrn eagbe rnq e bgguv egrra** to make a sentence, then a word you can make is *rearrangeable*. Funny that...

Comment: I'm legit scared to tackle the one with the movies. Um, I'm guessing most of them are horror movies (I know that the sixth sense is horror and Uninvited sounds creepy as heck) and I HATE (also scared) of horror movies. Enigma is a thriller (I think). Rest Im scared to look up. RIP me

Comment: Pretty sure the title of the puzzle is what the bonus level in LEGO Batman 3 is. Uh, and that’s copyright to my understanding or is there a bigger variety of things with this name?

Comment: @maounkhan "Same Bat-time, same bat-channel" is how they used to end episodes of the old Adam West Batman.  Might still be copyright, but that is the original reference.

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer:
The one in quotes that starts as jura qv, etc. is

> A rot13 cipher, which when decoded, shows this:
> when di dyo ulea rntor ead r otthi rteen?"
>  Which is "When did you learn to read rot thirteen?"

More partial answer:
The piano one can be referring to one of two things:

> It either means take every sixth letter after duh, which gives you role, and every eigth letter after duh, with gives you soe
>  It can also be reffering to music. A quaver is a nickname for an eight-note in muiscal notation. The 6 **duh** can refer to a 6/8 time signature, in which an eigth note is basically one whole beat, or a regular 4/4 siganture where an eigth note is 1/2 of a single beat.

Comment: It's a strange talent, that's for sure!

Comment: Did you decrypt that yourself or did you run it through a program? If you did it yourself, how?

Comment: I did it myself. Rot13 is a very simple cipher to solve. You just "shift" the plaintext letter A thirteen times to ciphertext "N" or plaintext letter A= Ciphertext N, B=O, etc. I've got familiar with rot13 to a point where I only put it through a program only when it is extremely long. I can usually just *read* rot13, but the weird spacing through me off a little bit so I had to get paper.

Comment: Added more to my answer